# Как отсортировать двусвязный список SplDoublyLinkedList?

Tags: php, алгоритм, односвязный-список, linked-list, двусвязный-список

Есть двусвязный список который мне нужно отсортировать за **O(n Log n)** время. Я бы хотел использовать `merge sort`, но я никак не могу сообразить, как это реализовать путём расширения класса `SplDoublyLinkedList` из стандартной библиотеки PHP.

Основная проблема в том, что я не могу разделить `SplDoublyLinkedList` пополам без выделения дополнительной памяти. Если бы я имел объекты отдельных нод, я бы легко мог установить указатель `next` ноды из середины списка на `null`, и сохранить указатель на следующую ноду в отдельную переменную, таким образом получив уже два связных списка. Но `SplDoublyLinkedList` не позволяет провернуть такую операцию.

Я имею ввиду нечто подобное в Java:

```
node mergeSort(node h) 
    { 
        if (h == null || h.next == null) { 
            return h; 
        } 

        node middle = getMiddle(h); 
        node nextOfMiddle = middle.next; 

        middle.next = null; 

        node left = mergeSort(h); 
        node right = mergeSort(nextofmiddle); 

        node sortedlist = sortedMerge(left, right); 
        return sortedlist; 
    }
```

Должен ли я действительно использовать `SplDoublyLinkedList` в этом случае, или мне  лучше написать свою собственую реализацию связного списка?

Comment: А не проще список преобразовать в массив, отсортировать массив и преобразовать результат обратно в список?

Comment: @tym32167 нет, не проще, т.к. это требует дополнительного выделения памяти.

Comment: Требует, но без константного времени на доступ к любому элементу списка по индексу как вы хотите уложиться в nLogn?

Comment: @tym32167 так рекурсивная сортировка слиянием обеспечивает в точности это время, я же привёл пример выше.

Comment: а, ну да, логично, Log(n) операций по n, сорян, я что то тупанул